# Проверить, является предложение вопросом

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

У меня есть большой объем сообщений, и мне нужно оставить среди них только те, которые являются вопросами. Эти сообщения -- выгрузка из телеграм-чата людей, перенесших определенные операции. В дальнейшем (после отсеивания невопросительных предложений) ее планируется разметить и использовать в обучении нейросети-классификатора.

Как эффективнее всего отсеить невопросительные предложения?

На самом деле я ищу что-то вроде `nltk.is_question()`

Я думал о проверке на наличе вопросительного знака и вопросительных слов в начале, но учитывая, что не все ставят вопросительные знаки в конце предложений, не думаю, что это будет лучший способ. В любом случае, относительно небольшой процент ошибки меня устроит. Спасибо.

**P.S.** Каждое сообщение представлено вот такой json-записью:

```
{
   "id": 00,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2019-00-00T00:00:00",
   "from": "Иван Иваной",
   "from_id": "user000000000",
   "text": "Текст сообщения здесь"
}
```

Comment: Даже предложения, начинающиеся с вопросительного слова, могут быть не вопросом, а уж о всех остальных вообще сложно что-то сказать без контекста.

Comment: @Эникейщик, добавил информации в вопрос, может это станет полезным. Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте поразмечать вручную, а потом какой нибудь классификатор интерпретируемый натравить. Ну или вручную проанализировать и признаки попытаться найти. Но сначала разметить.

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае, это недостижимо. Даже такое простое предложение как *"Это вопрос"* нельзя однозначно отнести к той или иной категории. В дополнении, вы не сможете проверить правильности категоризации, т.к. у вас, предполагаю, нет контакта автора сообщения, чтобы у него спросить, что он имел ввиду, вопрос или утверждение.

Может быть у вас есть какие-то еще признаки или мета-признаки?

Comment: Это выгрузка из телеграма, так что нет, только сообщение и id отправителя, но сообщений действительно много -- порядка 40 тысяч. Появилась идея выбрать все предложения со знаком вопроса и все предлоежния, которые начинаются с вопросительных местоимений. Небольшой процент ошибки в таком случае, в целом, устроит.

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, это уточняет задачу

Comment: добавил информации в вопрос, спасибо.